# GDB break on object function call

Tags: c++, gdb

I'm debugging an issue, and I want to break on every method call that has a specific object as the 'this' parameter.  Is this possible in GDB?

Comment: Do you mean a specific address? You can't get the object type from the this pointer.

Comment: You would have to use a conditional breakpoint. Those exist, but I have no idea how to set them up. gdb is largely a mystery to me, and the various guis around it do more to obscure than to make it accessible.

Comment: I do mean a specific adress - I have a object that is sticking around, and I want to know what is called on it.

Comment: @NathanielFlath: So, not only a single address, but you want to stop on each and every single method member function that is called with that address as `this`?

Comment: @NathanielFlath: My guess is that this can't be done easily without setting a conditional breakpoint of the type mentioned in the best answer on each and every method of the appropriate class. I might be wrong. It might be possible for gdb to list (and operate on) some sort of wildcard that would match all the methods of a class. That would be a really neat feature to have.

Comment: @NathanielFlath - I wonder if the gdb `rbreak` command in combination with the `if` clause mentioned below might not do what you want.

Answer (score 9):

It's easy. You can use command like `b A::a if (this==0x28ff1e)`.

Comment: Is it possible to specify a wildcard in place of `A::a` that would match the names of all methods in the `A` class?

Comment: I don't know any way to use wildcard in gdb, maybe he need a program to generate commands to set breaks.

Comment: @NathanielFlath - You know I wonder if the gdb `rbreak` command might not do what you want...

Comment: For some reason, I need to use the version without parentheses like `b A::a if this==0x28ff1e`

Answer (score 0):

The this parameter should only be the methods that are included in the class itself.  So you should just need to set breakpoints for all Of the methods of the class you are looking at.  I'm not sure there is a simple way to do that though.

Comment: I assumed the OP had a specific method in mind. But I suspect your interpretation is more correct. How would you set up such a breakpoint for even one method?

Answer (score 0):

> I want to break on every method call that has a specific object as the 'this' parameter

This means that you want to break on every member function of a particular class for which the object has been instantiated.

Let's say for convenience that all the member functions are defined in a particular cpp file such as `myclass_implementation.cpp`

You can use gdb to apply breakpoint on every function inside `myclass_implementation.cpp` this way:

```
rbreak myclass_implementation.cpp:.
```

Let's say you want to break on some specific functions such as getter functions which start with Get, then you can use gdb to apply breakpoints this way:

```
rbreak myclass_implementation.cpp:Get*
```